# C++: Create an anonymous class for event handlers

Tags: java, c++, qt, polymorphism, anonymous-types

**Disclaimer:** This description contains a lot of Qt specifics. They are not necessary to answer the question, I just wanted to give you the background.

I need to react on the `focusInEvent` of a `QTextEdit`.
Unfortunately this is not available as a signal, that's why I need to subclass `QTextEdit`. Since this is the only change I need, I would like to use an anonymous subclass

Like this:

```
myTextEdit =new QTextEdit(){
            void focusInEvent(){
     //code here
     }
};
```

This is the code I would write in Java, it doesn't compile in c++.
All following code is within the constructor of a custom `QWidget`. The `QTextEdit` is contained in this widget and should be initialized in its constructor.

Strangely this code compiles:

```
class MyTextEdit:protected QTextEdit{
    void focusInEvent();
};
auto myTextEdit=new MyTextEdit();
```

but is useless, since I can't assign an instance of `myTextEdit*` to a pointer to `QTextEdit`. Somehow polymorphism fails. This code doesn't compile:

```
class MyTextEdit:protected QTextEdit{
        void focusInEvent();
    };
QTextEdit* myTextEdit=new MyTextEdit();
```

The compiler error is:

> /home/lars/ProgrammierPraktikum/moleculator/implementation/Moleculator/gui_elements/editor.cpp:40:
>   error: 'QTextEdit' is an inaccessible base of
>   'Editor::Editor(std::shared_ptr)::MyTextEdit'
>        QTextEdit* myTextEdit=new MyTextEdit();

**Actual question:**

How do I create an anonymous subclass that is compatible to pointers of its superclass ?

Comment: Why do you use protected inheritance? If you use public inheritance, then you last example will compile.

Comment: Maybe have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368619/can-i-create-anonymous-classes-in-c-and-capture-the-outside-variables-like-in

Comment: @ThomasSparber, I need to override the event. It is marked as virtual protected.

Comment: @ThomasSparber, I looked at that question, but the problem is not the same. The other question asks how to capture outside variables. I don't need any outside variables, I just want to modify the textfield on its focus event. My problem is the type of the anonymous class

Comment: I do not understand you comment about the event being marked as virtual protected. If the event is a class, "marked as virtual proteced" doesnt make much sense to me. And btw, why is this tagged as java?

Comment: you mean `focusInEvent()` is protected and virtual in the base class?? If so, you are confusing some stuff and there is no problem to inherit publicly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subclassing attempt

```
class MyTextEdit:protected QTextEdit{
        void focusInEvent();
    };
QTextEdit* myTextEdit=new MyTextEdit();
```

Is almost ok.

Just because the method is protected doesn't mean you should inherit with protected.

- A protected method says: This is not part of my interface. Nobody but me should be able to call this. I will call this myself (as a part of the event handling). The method may be overriden in subclasses.
- Inheriting protected says: Nobody should know about this inheritance, it is an implementation detail that might be useful to classes extending me.

You want the regular public inheritance.

```
class MyTextEdit:public QTextEdit{
        void focusInEvent();
    };
QTextEdit* myTextEdit=new MyTextEdit();
```

Now you are saying that MyTextEdit is a replacement for a QTextEdit. 
You might want to add a constructor to supply the parent widget to MyTextEdit.

There is no such thing as a java-like anonymous inner class in c++.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need subclassing at all. You can convert events to signals using a helper class that can be applied to any event type, on any object. The `EventSignaler` acts as an event filter for one or more objects. It emits the `eventSignal` when a matching event has reached a given object.

```
class EventSignaler : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   QMap<QObject*, QSet<int>> m_watch;
   bool eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * ev) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
      auto it = m_watch.find(obj);
      if (it != m_watch.end() && it.value().contains(ev->type()))
         emit eventSignal(EventWrapper(obj, ev));
      return false;
   }
public:
   EventSignaler(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
   void watch(QObject * object, QEvent::Type type) {
      auto it = m_watch.find(object);
      if (it == m_watch.end()) {
         it = m_watch.insert(object, QSet<int>() << type);
         object->installEventFilter(this);
         connect(object, &QObject::destroyed, this, [this, object]{
            m_watch.remove(object);
         });
      } else
         it.value().insert(type);
   }
   void unWatch(QObject * object, QEvent::Type type) {
      auto it = m_watch.find(object);
      if (it == m_watch.end()) return;
      it.value().remove(type);
      if (it.value().isEmpty()) m_watch.erase(it);
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void eventSignal(const EventWrapper &);
};
```

The `EventWrapper` is a helper class used to represent the type of an event and safely carry the pointer to an event. When the class is copied, e.g. when it is delivered via a *queued* connection, the original event won't exist anymore, so the wrapper zeroes out the event pointer. This is necessary, since the events generally are not copyable.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/event-signaler-32648234
#include <QtWidgets>

struct EventWrapper {
   QPointer<QObject> target;
   QEvent::Type type { QEvent::None };
   QEvent * event { nullptr };
public:
   EventWrapper() {}
   EventWrapper(QObject * target, QEvent * event) :
      target(target), type(event->type()), event(event) {}
   EventWrapper(const EventWrapper & o) : target(o.target), type(o.type) {}
   EventWrapper(EventWrapper && o) :
      target(o.target), type(o.type), event(o.event) { o.event = nullptr; }
   EventWrapper & operator=(const EventWrapper & o) {
      target = o.target;
      type = o.type;
      event = nullptr;
      return *this;
   }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(EventWrapper)
```

Finally, we can demonstrate all this on a little example with a label and a line edit. The text from the line edit is copied to the label whenever you click on the label.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   EventSignaler signaler;
   QWidget w;
   QVBoxLayout layout(&w);
   QLabel label("text");
   QLineEdit edit;
   layout.addWidget(&label);
   layout.addWidget(&edit);
   signaler.watch(&label, QEvent::MouseButtonPress);
   QObject::connect(&signaler, &EventSignaler::eventSignal,
                    [&label, &edit]{ label.setText(edit.text()); });
   w.show();
   return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: very helpful. This was the way I actually did it. Had to accept the other question as an answer though, since the question was explicitly qt independent